# Infinite recursion on adding days to a SimpleDate python object created from UTC

Tags: python, recursion, timedelta

I am using the python library simple-date. I created a SimpleDate object by initializing with a string representing a UTC date. When I try to add days to it, using timedelta, it seems to work fine but then when I try to print it, it recurses infinitely. I inspected the object resulting from the addition with p in the debugger and it displays nothing. The type is SimpleDate but it seems empty somehow. If I dont use a UTC string, it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong ?

My code:

```
from simpledate import SimpleDate
from datetime import timedelta

# This works
day = '2016-06-01 00:00:00'
later = SimpleDate(day) + timedelta(days=10)
print(later)

# This works
day = '2016-06-01 00:00:00'
later = SimpleDate(day) + timedelta(days=10)
print(later)

# The print statement will cause infinite recursion
day = '2016-06-01 00:00:00'
later = SimpleDate(day, tz='UTC') + timedelta(days=10)
print(later)

# The print statement will cause infinite recursion
day = '2016-06-01 00:00:00UTC'
later = SimpleDate(day) + timedelta(days=10)
print(later)
```

Comment: I am using Python 3.5 and [simple-date](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-date)

Comment: hi, this is simple-date author.  this sounds like a bug, sorry!  i'll try fix it this weekend and will post here when done.

Comment: ok, i understand this, but it will be tomorrow or sunday before i have some tests, build a new release, etc.  a quick workaround for now is to use the utc attribute of your UTC datetime:  later = SimpleDate(day, tz='UTC').utc + timedelta(days=10) i'll post a detailed explanation of why later.

Comment: hi.  i'm afraid i've found some more problems with the package - it appears that something in recent python regexp handling has changed.  so i cannot make a release yet, although the latest release in git at https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-date fixes your immediate issue.  i will continue to work on this.  sorry for the delay.

Comment: Hello Andrew, it is awesome that you did take action already!! I understand that changes in regexp makes the fix less easy to fix but I do appreciate the workaround. Will try it on Monday. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

So, there were two issues here.

The first is easy to explain.  Generating a message for a certain error caused the same error it was trying to report.  That caused a new message to be generated, which caused a new error, which ... eventually exhausted the stack.  That is now fixed.

The second is harder to explain, because timezones are complicated.  So I will start by giving an example that is easier to understand.  Consider this date in PDT (Pacific Daylight Time):

```
>>> SimpleDate('2016-08-28', tz='PDT')
SimpleDate('2016-08-28')
```

if we add 6 months to that, we will be in the middle of winter.  PDT doesn't even **exist** then (it's winter)!  So we get an error:

```
>>> SimpleDate('2016-08-28', tz='PDT') + timedelta(days=180)
simpledate.SingleInstantTzError: Attempted to use PDT, defined only for 2016-08-28 07:00:00+00:00
```

Now you could argue that SimpleDate should be smart enough to know when PDT ends.  But it isn't (and afaik it just doesn't have the data available, but I may be wrong).  Instead, SimpleDate **refuses to modify dates associated with timezones that may have limited validity**.  That's what "single instant" means.

For more on this see [the documentation](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-date#why-did-i-get-the-error-singleinstanttzerror-).

But in this case, the timezone was UTC!  We know that is always valid.  So I have added a special case that avoids this restriction when parsing UTC:

```
>>> SimpleDate('2016-08-28', tz='UTC') + timedelta(days=180)
SimpleDate('2017-02-24', tz='UTC')
```

This is now in PyPI as release 0.5.0.  Sorry for the delay - some tests were failing and I found a new bug, so I needed to do some extra work.

Comment: Awesome ! It works very well now ! My issue is fixed ! Thanks a whole lot !